# Retrieving null as JSON default in django and MySQL

Tags: python, django

I have a JSON column in MySQL:

1. Should be null if the admins give it the default value.
2. Preload with the default value to admins if it is null.

Using **django-mysql** third party library

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import JSONField

def json_default():
    return {'foo': '', 'bar': ''}

class Test(models.Model):

    json_field = JSONField(default=json_default)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = models.Model.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if name == 'json_field' and not attr:
            return json_default()
        return attr

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if all(value.strip() == '' for value in self.json_field.values()):
            self.json_field = None
        else:
            self.json_field = {k:v.strip() for k, v in self.json_field.items()}
        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is whenever the **super** method is called, **__getattribute__** is internally called and as a result, it saves as json_default() and not null.

Answer (score 0):

Got a hacky solution to handle the problem, please let me know if there are better ways to implement.

PS: I'm a novice in python and Django.

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import JSONField

def json_default():
    return {'foo': '', 'bar': ''}

class Test(models.Model):

    json_field = JSONField(default=json_default, blank=True, null=True)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = models.Model.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if name == 'json_field':
            if attr is None: # while get from db
                return json_default()
            elif attr == json_default(): # while save to db
                return None
        return attr


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.json_field is not None:
            self.json_field = {k:v.strip() for k, v in self.json_field.items()}
        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```